# Modifying strings in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a string here in python '#b9d9ff'. How do I remove the hash symbol (#)?

Comment: Worth pointing out: strings in Python are immutable. The string you get back with `'#b9d9ff'.replace('#','')` is not a modified version of the original, but a brand new one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are various trivially-different options. Each one does the same thing for your string but handles other strings differently.

```
# Strip any hashes on the left.
string.lstrip('#')

# Remove hashes anywhere in the string, not necessarily just from the front.
string.replace('#', '')

# Remove only the first hash in the string.
string.replace('#', '', 1)

# Unconditionally remove the first character, no matter what it is.
string[1:]

# If the first character is a hash, remove it. Otherwise do nothing.
import re
re.sub('^#', '', string)
```

(If you don't care which, use `lstrip('#')`. It is the most self-descriptive.)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> '#bdd9ff'[1:]
'bdd9ff'
>>> '#bdd9ff'.replace('#', '')
'bdd9ff'
```

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, you cannot modify strings in python at all.  Strings are an immutable type.  If it is sufficient for your needs to return new strings with the desired modification, then the other answers do just that.  If you really need a mutable type, you can use a list of single character strings, or you can use the `array` module's `array.fromstring()` or `array.fromunicode()` methods, or in newer python versions, the `bytearray` type.